# AOSP building : Make file shared libraries issue

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-source

Following is my **MAKE** file for the source that i'm compiling with the build **AOSP**

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= abc.c

LOCAL_MODULE:= abc

LOCAL_FORCE_STATIC_EXECUTABLE := true

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libc

LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_OPTIONAL_EXECUTABLES)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := debug

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../external/sqlite/dist \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../external/sqlite/android 

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
        libsqlite \
 libsqlite3_android

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

here, in the source `abc.c` i'm trying to use the functions declared in `sqlite3.h`. When i'm trying to build the android source it is returning error

```
no rule libsqlite3_android.so  to make target abc.so
```

i want to link the sqlite library to my source file.

Plz help me to find where i'm going wrong and how can i solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have built SQLite3 before. (You should build the whole project before add any new stuff or customize any code)

Second, make sure you are build the same target product when you build the SQLite3. (Make sure you have select the correct menu when you do 'lunch').

Last, make sure the SQLite3 objects is in the target folders. YOURANDROIDROOT/out/target/PRODUCTNAME/system/symbols...

Comment: how?? can u suggest any change that might be helpful in above make file

Comment: Your MK file seems OK, except for only one thing that you could try to replace LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES  with LOCAL_LD_LIBRARIES. My point is that you should make sure the SQLite dependency is already there in your target product symbols follder

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you shouldn't have to link with libsqlite3_android library.

According to the AOSP libsqlite makefile (`external/sqlite/android/Android.mk`), libsqlite3_android is a STATIC library which is included in the libsqlite dynamic library (`external/sqlite/dist/Android.mk`).

So linking with libsqlite should be enough.